# How do you turn on/off Linux kernel Virtio features?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bitmap, operating-system, virtio

Virtio documentation, like [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/659c36fcda403013a01b85da07cf2d9711e6d6c7/Documentation/virtual/virtio-spec.txt), describes many feature bits that can be set or "negotiated" for a virtio-device. For instance, there is the `VIRTIO_RING_F_EVENT_IDX` feature that can be turned on or off.

I have not come across any documentation that describes how to actually turn features on or off. Is there any way to turn features on or off at runtime (like through a `/proc/` variable)? Are features something to be configured using `make menuconfig` when compiling a kernel? Or is the only way to modify the source code of a  virtio device file and add/remove features there (like modifying this [enum in vhost/vhost.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/vhost/vhost.h#L256))?

Comment: If you wanted a feature to be disabled you could add a kernel command-line parameter to the driver and do it at reboot. As mentioned below, it is not possible at runtime.

Comment: @stark: Driver command-line parameter would be a good way to do that, but I was under the impression that if the driver is built as a module, you can supply parameters at `insmod` time.  You're only restricted to "at reboot" if the driver is loaded at boot.  Are virtio drivers incompatible with module loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other comments and the other answer, there is no way to add/remove features for a virtio-device at runtime.

To change a virtio feature, you must modify the corresponding driver and device source code.

As an example, the [enum in vhost/vhost.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/vhost/vhost.h#L256) you linked to is inside a driver file (the full path is actually `drivers/vhost/vhost.h`). So for turning off a feature, you could set features to false from this enum and reload the driver. For adding a feature, though, modifying the driver alone is not sufficient.

To add a feature for a virtio driver/device, you need to make sure that the feature bit is turned on in both the virtio driver (guest-level) and the device (host-level). You already know how to modify the driver code, so the only piece is how to modify the device level feature.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318774/13020139), device level features can be turned on/off by modifying the emulator code, typically Qemu. The `VIRTIO_RING_F_EVENT_IDX` feature you mentioned can be found in Qemu on [this line](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/include/hw/virtio/virtio.h#L361), set to true by default (as of version 8.1.2).

Comment: You can also enable or disable in the qemu command line, no need to recompile qemu. -device virtio-net-pci,event_idx=off should do the trick. And there are XML parameters for that in libvirt too.

The linux virtio driver does not have code for that by today, but there is nothing fundamental that makes impossible to add code to check it.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Virtio Committee specification, v1.2, describes the virtio feature bits [here](https://docs.oasis-open.org/virtio/virtio/v1.2/cs01/virtio-v1.2-cs01.html#x1-140002).  Specifically:

> Each virtio device offers all the features it understands. During
> device initialization, the driver reads this and tells the device the
> subset that it accepts. The only way to renegotiate is to reset the
> device.
>
> This allows for forwards and backwards compatibility: if the device is
> enhanced with a new feature bit, older drivers will not write that
> feature bit back to the device. Similarly, if a driver is enhanced
> with a feature that the device doesn’t support, it see the new feature
> is not offered.

So the answer is:  you need to decide at initialization time which feature(s) you want your device to support and prepare to do the feature negotiation properly per the [Device Initialization](https://docs.oasis-open.org/virtio/virtio/v1.2/cs01/virtio-v1.2-cs01.html#x1-1070001) section.

Suggestion:  If you're going to invest seriously in virtio driver development, check out the [virtio-comment](https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/virtio-comment/) mailing list.  Best of luck :-@)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To clarify, I'm asking how to turn on a feature from a user perspective. As in, if I want to play around with an existing device driver, how do I turn the feature on/off? So when you say "decide at initialization time" does that mean "hard code in the driver source file"?

Comment: I think OP is looking for ways to do this from userspace, not kernel space / driver code. The proper answer would be that what OP is asking for is not possible by design, and your current answer sort of explains why.